# Problem with one process and different pallet racks: Store pallets only when pallet racks have space

Tags: anylogic

I would like to avoid an error so I have several pallet racks where I would like to store my different pallet types if my pallet racks have enough space. If not, the pallet should wait until space is available. With a restricted area it doesn't work to determine the max. space of every pallet rack on its own. Because of my different pallet racks in **ONE process** by getpalletrack() I have a total max. capacity but I need the maximal space for every pallet rack.

**Example**:
I have 2 pallet racks with `typeID`=1 and `typeID`=10. `typeID1` =PRD32 `typeID10`= PRD31
Capacity for every pallet rack = 45
So it doesn't work to set the restricted area to 45 because **I need the space of 45 for every pallet rack and the restricted area determine it in total 45 for both.** When restricted area is 45 it stores only 45 pallets but the capacity of two pallet racks is 90.

So what I need is a function or a block where every pallet rack in my process gets a restricted area on its own that they can use their complete capacity. Currently the restricted area ensures that my racks logically don't use their capacity because the restricted area restricts the racks in total and not every rack on its own.
[image: process]

[image: dbase]

[image: getmypalletrack]

Comment: forget getMyPalletRack function and use a selectOutput to send the agents to different storeRawmaterial blocks and if you have 1000 pallet racks, then use exit blocks and agents that represent your palletracks

Comment: @Felipe with selectOutput can I also determine in which pallet rack my pallet types have to go? I only have 3 pallet racks at the moment.

Comment: The better question is how I integrate the if else function above into select output

Comment: if you don't know how to use a selectoutput, then i suggest you go directly to the help documentation to learn one of the most basic blocks in AnyLogic... Jack this is so amazingly basic, that I don't even know how to start explaining it